# Load another page with DOM changing

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to load from **initial.html** different html page with:

```
$("#hidden_demo_div").load("modules/another.html", function (data) {
    var value = $(data).filter("#demo_div");
    var html = value.html(); // THERE IS NO <strong>Hello</strong> here!!!
}
```

here a snippet from **another.html**

```
<html>
    .........................
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
             anotherMethodInvocation();
        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <div id="demo_div"></div>
</html>
```

next at JS for **another.html** I have:

```
function anotherMethodInvocation() {    
    $("#demo_div").append("<strong>Hello</strong>");
}
```

So the question is why am I getting (in my callback function at load) just static HTML but not it changes?

**UPDATE 1:**

a) The "#hidden_demo_div" is at the **initial.html** (HTML where JS code with .load is linked). 
This element is declared at the BODY :

b) It DOES NOT work even if I put at the BODY 
(to one html file)

```
<div id="hidden_demo_div"></div>
```

and
(to another html file)

```
<div id="demo_div"></div>
```

at the BODY.

Comment: You have no **<body>** tag after the head section.

Comment: How does your structure look? I mean your files and from where is this method run?

Comment: Please provide some more information about the JS that has anotherMethodInvocation(). Does it linked in index html or another.html?

Comment: If you add a body tag it works. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/BPYCE/)

Comment: @Bruno Unfortunately no. Your Fiddle example hasn't .load fun invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to realize that when loading a remote page the `ready` event has already occured in the main page. This means that code wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() {}` in the remote page will fire instantly.

If the code in the remote file precedes the html it refers to it will not find that html as it doesn't exist at the time the code fires.

Try this structure in the remote page:

```
<div id="demo_div"></div>
<!--  "demo_div" now exists , can run code on it -->
<script type="text/javascript">            
       anotherMethodInvocation();

</script>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready` is the equivalent of setting a short timeout if the document is already ready at the time of the call, it will not run synchronously. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L845

Comment: @Esailija not when it is used in an ajax loaded page...  `ready` has already occured

Comment: no... script can be placed in head or body. As I've shown you need to place code in body after the html it refers to

Comment: an alternative is to place script in external file and use `$.getScriot` in `load` callback